# How do I get the line of text under the cursor in a TextView in gtk#?

Tags: gtk#

I have a GTK# TextView and I want to read the **line of text under the cursor**. I don't see a single method that will do that, so I think I need to combine several method calls, like `Buffer.GetText`, `Buffer.GetIterAtOffset`, `Buffer.CursorPosition`, but it's not obvious to me what the right combination is.

Comment: I have found an alternate approach to my problem that doesn't depend on doing this, so it's no longer important to me to find an answer. Still, it might be important to someone, so I hope this finds an answer.

Answer (score 1):

TextIter are a bit odd to use. Buffer.CursorPosition gives you the current position.

It's easy to find the end of the line:

```
var end = Buffer.CursorPosition;
end.ForwardToLineEnd();
```

To get the first character, there's not symetrical method, so you might try:

```
var start = Buffer.CursorPosition;
start.BackwardChars(start.LineOffset); // LineOffset gives you the iter offset on the current line.
```